# SQL - how to insert new rows attached to Id from another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In this case I have two tables in MySql DB. First is **User** entity and second entity is **Notification**. Those entites are related in structure.

Notification entity looks like this:

```
id    newsletter    type     user_id
1         0         EMAIL        5
2         1         SMS          5
3         1         FACEBOOK     5
4         1         EMAIL        7
5         0         SMS          7
6         0         FACEBOOK     7
```

How sql statement should look like to insert new row for each user_id

I tried something like this or first get all users from this table and for each iterate and insert values.

```
INSERT INTO db.notification (newsletter, type, user_id) select true, 'GOOGLE', user_id  foreach existing user from db.notification
```

So output would look like:

```
id    newsletter    type     user_id
1         0         EMAIL        5
2         1         SMS          5
3         1         FACEBOOK     5
4         1         EMAIL        7
5         0         SMS          7
6         0         FACEBOOK     7
7         1         GOOGLE       5
8         1         GOOGLE       7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO db.notification (newsletter, type, user_id)
    select distinct true, 'GOOGLE', user_id  
    from db.notification ;
```